# Paper tape surfacing after sanding

Tags: drywall

If paper tape surfaces after sanding, particularly in corners, is it better to score around the blister and tear it off, then fill the hole with mud OR apply another layer in the expanded area around the surfacing although that may add unwanted thickness?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a blister, cut it out as proposed. If it is tape that's showing due to over-sanding or lack of proper plaster thickness, apply more mud with successively wider knives until the tape is covered properly.